# Get all rows where the permutation of column a and b is unique

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch all rows from a table where the permutation of `column_a` and `column_b` is unique

```
column_a column_b
1         2
1         5
2         1
1         2
```

the query should select

```
column_a column_b
1         2
1         5
2         1
```

I have seen other posts on this matter, but they all seem to focus on both columns being unique separately, so that column_a can never present the same value twice. This is not what I am trying to do.

---

Even better would be to have a query that selects all rows where this permutation is not unique -- the reason I am doing this is that i then need to run some logic to decide which of the duplicate rows needs to stay and which need to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upvoted the previous answers as they provide an answer to the main question:

`fetch all rows from a table where the permutation of column_a and column_b is unique`

However, I ended up using a combination of the answers provided to `find all rows where the permutation of column_a and column_b is not unique`. The reason is that i wanted to see all the rows that had duplicate `column_a` and `column_b` and not just one of them.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT column_a, column_b
FROM table 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    GROUP BY column_a, column_b
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`DISTINCT` filters out repeated **rows**. Please note `DISTINCT` applies to the full row.

```
select distinct column_a, column_b from my_table
```

And for your second question:

> ...a query that selects all rows where this permutation is not unique...

```
select column_a, column_b
from my_table
group by column_a, column_b
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the combinations that are unique:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM theTable
GROUP BY a, b
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

...and changing that `=` to `<>` will give you the non-unique ones.

If you're trying to eliminate duplicates, and have another identifying field (like an auto-incremented PK), you can just select the ones you want to keep by selecting `MIN(id)` or `MAX(id)` along with the pairing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, in my case the one to keep does not depend on when they were inserted (I am guessing that's what the MIN(id) and MAX(id) did)

Comment: Yeah, I was just using it as an example. However, if your "keep" calculation's result can be expressed numerically, MIN/MAX could still be used in conjunction with it.